# as3 library for transforming images during runtime(scale, rotate, skew)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone know any as3 libraries that allow you to scale, rotate, skew, etc.. images during runtime? I have found the [greensock transform manager class](http://www.greensock.com/transformmanageras3/), but would prefer not to pay $300.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Transformer class in my Quasimondolibs
http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/source/browse/#svn/trunk/quasimondolibs/com/quasimondo/tools

Here is a little example:
http://www.quasimondo.com/examples/transformer/

Example's source:
http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/source/browse/trunk/examples/Transformer/src/TransformerDemo.as

Of course since there is no $300 price tag on it it comes without documentation or support. But as you can see in the example the usage is relatively simple.  Also it does not have fancy features, like group transformations. If you want to do that you have to add those elements to a parent holder and add the transformer to that one.

Comment: My company ended up purchasing the transform manager from greensock. It was a small price to pay for a large project. It's great to work with, totally worth it.

But I will still try out your class, I'm sure it is great, I have used a lot of your things in the past and found great success. Thanks!